# FFmpeg command profiles for all devices

Tags: php, audio, video, ffmpeg

I want to build online Audio/Video Converter with PHP.

I want to allow users to convert videos automatically without extra configuration like (Bit rate, codec, etc...) by just selecting device name [Ex: Samsung Galaxy S5].

So, I want pre configured file. That contains video configurations of all devices...

Please help me? About this. Open source project.

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg can convert virtually between any video and audio formats.

So assign "default" extension to every supported device and execute FFmpeg conversion with default values. Most of values are set by default, so all you need to do in CLI:

```
ffmpeg -i InputFile.mov OutputFile.mpeg
```

If need any additional parameters to specify, use [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html). Just keep in mind, that most of parameters position has different impact on output file (wasted around 6h looking for that "bug").

Comment: I know this. But, this is not suitable for my purpose.

Comment: @N41TKD so what is suitable for you than? `Device name` != `supported extension`, you have to define some parameters for device or it's groups

Answer (score 0):

You have to check data sheets for every device. There is no "magic" table that I know of that includes every device in existence. You can check [FFmpeg wiki](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#Compatibility) to get started.